# Настройка php парсера (Как не учитывать символы)

Tags: php, парсер

есть php парсер для загрузки прайса на сайт. В прайсе есть столбец PCD (как и на сайте одноименный фильтр), в котором опции в виде "4х100", "5х112", "4х98", "NxN". При загрузке прайса, парсер добавляет в фильтр соответствующие опции.
Как сделать, чтобы парсер при загрузке прайса и добавлении опций в данный фильтр не учитывал 4х, 5х, т.е. добавлял опции "98", "100", "112" и т.д., а часть "Nx" обрезал?

Comment: какой именно парсер вы используете?

Comment: PHP самопис загружающий данные из xls таблиц

Comment: либо регуляркой убрать, либо explode()

Comment: А как это непосредственно в коде отразить? Т.к. я в php совсем профан

Answer (score 0):

```
// $v - это строка из которой нужно достать нужную часть = '123'
// и три варианта как можно «достать» эту нужную часть..

$v = '4x123';

// первый вариант..
print strrev((int)strrev($v));

// второй вариант.. 
print explode('x', $v, 2)[1];

// третий вариант..     
print preg_replace('/.*?(\d+$)/', '$1', $v);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]